# Minutes package: Change the preformatted texts in the maketitle segment

Tags: renewcommand, minutes

I want the `\moderation{}` command to display `Chairman` instead of `Moderation`. Is that possible?

Document class: `scrartcl`

Previously tried:

1. `\renewcommand{\moderation}{Chairman}` inside and outside of minutes and document environment
2. ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{minutes}{\renewcommand{\moderation}{Chairman}}
   ```

outside of minutes environment

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ListTitle]{minutes}

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Titel} %Titel

\moderation{Mister X}
\maketitle

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, added the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `\min@textModerator` macro like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ListTitle]{minutes}

\makeatletter
\def\min@textModerator{Chairman}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Titel} %Titel

\moderation{Mister X}
\maketitle

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! But how would the command change when using the [ngerman] in babel? Did not have in mind that this will make a difference, but so it is. Changed the MWE to account for usepackage babel.

Comment: @Flexi If you have a new question, please ask a new question. It is very frowned upon to edit a question in a way which invalidates an existing answer.